# How can I fix No loadImage callback was specified to load the image with id error

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

How can I fix No loadImage callback was specified to load the image with id error.
I need to use xml string dynamically like this.
how can i add the picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `image` attributes in the ribbon XML markup you need to specify the `loadImage` attribute for the `customUI` tag.

---

There are two major ways for loading images in the Fluent UI:

1. The `<customUI>` element's `loadImage` attribute enables you to specify a callback that can load all images. After you set up this callback procedure, Office calls the callback procedure and passes the string from the image attribute for each control that loads images. You do not need to implement the `getImage` callback multiple times, such as one time for each control that requires images. For example, a customization might include markup like the following.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" 
  loadImage="GetImage">
<!-- Later in the markup -->
   <button id="myButton" image="mypic.jpg" />
```

To supply the button's image, Office calls the `GetImage` function. It passes the parameter "mypic.jpg" and expects an `IPictureDisp` object in return. By using this technique, you can write a single callback procedure that returns all the images your customization needs, without having to write each individual control's `getImage` callback. Note that the `loadImage` callback is not called again when you call the Ribbon's `Invalidate` method or `InvalidateControl` method. For the controls that need to change images dynamically at run time, use the `getImage` callback.

2. The `getImage` attribute for controls which allows specifying a callback to load images dynamically.

Read more about that in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: thank you i solved the problem with loadImage